# SQL Server table which preserve only differences

Tags: sql-server, logging, datatables, bigdata

I have small task to create logging table in SQL Server which preserve only differences, because I am going log stream data every second, and most of time, difference will be quite small. [DateIndex] and change in 1 column value.

Example:

```
DateIndex C1 C2  C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
---------------------------------
1         1   2  3  4  5  6  7.0
2         1   2  3  0  5  6  7.1
3         1   0  3  4  5  6  7.3
```

Is there any way to have table which only write down difference, not whole row?

Comment: What would that accomplish? It would only make querying a *lot* slower . BTW `every second` isn't a lot of data. Only 3600 rows per *hour*. SQL Server has transparent data compression, columnstore indexes and in-memory tables even in the Express edition (since 2016 SP1). A typical architecture eg for event analytics is to create an in-memory table for event ingestion (assuming there are a *lot* of events per second) and a columnstore index for longer term storage and analytics

Comment: I have 20 Gb on disk just for 1 table after 1 year, and seldom need data so old. I always need data for couple days MAX. Obviosly logging tables are very typical task and usually done by logging into files, but I am puzzled to find solution for this in SQL Server, as I need log it into table.

Comment: 20GB isn't a lot. You can reduce it if you use compression. You can use partitioning (also available in Express) and either discard old partitions or move them to other, slower disks. You can mark older partitions as `readonly` which improves compression, especially in columnstores.

Comment: Columnstores are *particularly attractive* as they only store unique values per column (well, bucket). Storing 10000 times the value 1 only stores it once. They also have a natural form of partitioning as the columnstore index is "partitioned" into buckets of ~1M rows each. New rows are added into a new bucket and when that fills, the bucket is "closed". If you only append records to the table, you have time-based partitioning out of the box

Comment: never used columstores, I will check them too. They might solve my task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements and SQL Server version, this sounds like a job for either [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (CDC), available in SQL Server 2008 and above, or [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017), available in SQL Server 2016 and above.

CDC uses the transaction log to capture inserts, updates, and deletes in a system generated change log table, in the System Tables area of your database, and retains data for a configurable period of time. The default is three days, but you can set that to as long or as short a period as makes sense for your needs. The table contains all inserts, all deletes, and a before and after snapshot for updates.

With a temporal table, a History table is created within the main Tables area of your database. The main temporal table contains the current state of your data and the history table contains all the changes. The temporal tables give you the advantage of being able to write a query that will return data as it existed at a point in time. It stores data through the beginning of time out of the box, though, so it can be a little storage intensive in a high-flow application.

I'd look into both before starting down the path of a roll-your-own solution.

Comment: Temporal Tables looks exactly what I have in mind, as it have time vector. I will try it. Thank you for help.

Comment: Neither CDC nor temporal tables reduce the load or improve performance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no argument on either point. I haven't worked with any temporal tables that were subjected to any meaningful load, but I've implemented CDC on some reasonably high volume databases (more transactions than the OP is talking about; ~100/second) without any noticeable performance hit. Since it's asynchronous, the change tables can experience a few seconds of lag, but that was the only negative we saw.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you care to actually write the CURRENT data into a table, you can have deltas generated automatically by a trigger. Still have to write those to a proper table, though, no way around that.

Comment: I can do it, but I need some presentation layer which give me data by time.  If I make format myself to save only differences, it will be very complicated.